# Transfer functions in R (TSA package)

Tags: r, time-series, arima

In Time Series models’ transfer functions there is a decay parameter in the
formula (let’s call it b). In TSA package that decay parameter is not mentioned. When I used other software before (such as SAS) I used to determine b after analyzing ‘prewhitened series’. But
in TSA package in R there is no need to specify the decay parameter once you analyze CCF?

If not how am I going to know when the decay starts?

I understand CCF is used after prewhitening to determine how to
filter the outputs but where b comes into the picture?

Comment: Which function in TSA are you using to fit transfer function models?

Comment: It is important to clearly identify the specific function you refer to.

Answer (score 0):

Standard notation for identifying a Transfer Function includes r,s and b

r is the number of denominator coefficients 
s is the number of numerator coefficients
and 
b is the pure delay or dead time before y responds to x

AUTOBOX  a piece of software that I have helped develop does this ( at the user's option ) automatically or a user can specify the model themselves. You can freely download a 30 day version from (http://www.autobox.com) and play it with and compare your model identification with it's suggestion. It is a great(free) way of learning how to identify this class of model.